# AHCI mode gave me two boot options

Tags: windows-7, pata

Ok so I've had my SSD running for a few months and things were good. Then I read an article about how AHCI was better than IDE. So I switched the mode to AHCI and it wants me to reinstall Windows 7. So I put in the disc, I delete the one partition, create a new one, reinstall, all good.

But now when I boot it says it found two OS's, both Windows 7. The first one works, its the new install. The second one is junk, it tells me the whole spiel about the windows install being hosed. The same message the old install gave me right after I switched to AHCI.

Any way to delete this second boot entry?

Comment: You switched it *from* the better mode *to* the less-good mode?

Comment: sorry, mispoke. I went from IDE to AHCI. And my CrystalDiskMark scores went way up, so I assume I'm in AHCI mode now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You to remove the second boot entry you want to edit the boot manager files. There is a command tool for this on the windows DVD, but an easier solution is to use a tool called *EasyBCD*

Also nice to know: AHCI uses different drivers than IDE. With win7 you no longer need to reinstall your whole OS when you have your boot drive on the controller which you switched from IDE to AHCI. Instead do this:

1. Start Regedit
2. Open HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / SYSTEM / CurrentControlset / Services
3. Open msahci
4. In the right field left click on "start" and go to Modify
5. In the value Data field enter "0" and click "ok"
6. exit "Regedit"
7. Reboot and enable AHCI in the BIOS

Comment: Nice tip dude. Where were you 8 hrs ago? Actually I love wiping the system and starting fresh. New car smell.

Comment: you have the cave and pave addiction.  ;;-)