# Getting an IDE mode installation of 7 to run in AHCI mode?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, installation, ahci

I installed windows 7 a few months ago while my SATAs in my bios were configured as IDE. When I change it to AHCI for an added speed boost, I get a BSOD on startup. Is there a way or tool I can use to get my OS to boot in ahci mode without reinstalling windows?

I tried the windows recovery and start up fixes but they did not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the tool is `regedit`.

You need to enable the AHCI part. Then shut down, turn AHCI on in the BIOS and boot into your faster system.

I had a post somewhere on StackExchange describing how to do that. I will look it up and link to it. Meanwhile try `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services`. Look for `msahci` and change the value to `0`.

Edit1:

Someone else answered the same thing but even added screenshots. That post is [here on superuser question 110927](https://superuser.com/questions/110927/enabling-ahci-on-sata-drive-in-windows-7)

Edit2: My old post [[AHCI mode gave me two boot options](https://superuser.com/questions/432022/ahci-mode-gave-me-two-boot-options)](https://superuser.com/questions/432022/ahci-mode-gave-me-two-boot-options).

```
Start Regedit
Open HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / SYSTEM / CurrentControlset / Services
Open msahci
In the right field left click on "start" and go to Modify
In the value Data field enter "0" and click "ok"
exit "Regedit"
Reboot and enable AHCI in the BIOS
```

Comment: A more detail list of instructions might be helpful.

Comment: Added a link to my old post and cut and pasted the instructions from the old post.