# Force ICH7-M AHCI mode works in Linux with grub2 and setpci, not in Windows

Tags: windows-7, grub, pci, dualboot, ahci

This is my first post, forgive me if I am in the wrong place or if my post is considered inappropriate.
I have borrowed the idea from numerous Mac user forums, after I added a SSD disk to my Sony VAIO VPCW12J1E, 32bit, dual booting Debian Sid / Windows 7 Starter on standard MBR - no GPT, no EFI, no UEFI.
The netbook is equipped with a heavily mutilated Phoenix BIOS, which lacks the option to set the chipset in AHCI mode (see my post [here](https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-REQUEST-Sony-VAIO-VPCW12J1E-R1100E1-ICH-SATA-PATA-Control-Sub-Menu-ahci-unlock?pid=190711#pid190711) for example).
With Debian already installed in IDE mode, and **initramfs-tools** package, it's all quite simple:

1. `nano /etc/initramfs-tools/modules` - at the end of the file, add a first line to load the module **ahci** and a second line for the module **libahci** ;
2. `nano /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/driver-policy` - change from **MODULES=dep** to **MODULES=list** ;
3. then regenerate yours initrd images - `update-initramfs -u -k all` and `lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-'uname -r' | grep -i ahci` just to be sure that the needed modules are in place;
4. `nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom` - write a custom **menuentry** and, immediately after the last line **initrd /initrd.img** just write **setpci -s 0:1f.2 90.b=40** and then close the stanza with the **}** symbol;
5. then `update-grub` ;
6. and lastly again `update-initramfs -u -k all` .

Reboot, choose your custom **menuentry**, enjoy Debian with SSD in AHCI mode (see [attachment #1](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1u4YIc0VG43Fv2oag360nZ5AQKemeHCOLeoyej5_SiGI/edit?usp=sharing) on my Google Drive).

With Windows is another story, the previous magic string does not suffice alone and indeed, it prevents the system from seeing the SSD disk - so it does not boot.
But I believe the SATA settings mentioned in the [official datasheet](https://www.intel.it/content/www/it/it/io/i-o-controller-hub-7-datasheet.html) can be translated into other **setpci** strings.
I can provide whole PCI configuration space of my ICH7-M in IDE and AHCI mode to get a diff (see [attachment #2](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rF08mIFYFwcRjQK04mynPvlCc06Rr2Bw-NSNFJ9AKDc/edit?usp=sharing)) but I would need a lot of help translating the differences into the right strings.

edit

Following for example post #7 [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120712131331/http:/forum.notebookreview.com/hardware-components-aftermarket-upgrades/460478-ich7-m.html), I tried with **grub4dos**, from an MS-DOS floppy (I have a USB floppy drive) with a setpci compiled with DJGPP from [here](https://github.com/HowardHo2021/flashrom-DOS-port/releases/tag/2021-10-10) - tracing the various values of the offsets from the linux lspci dump of the ICH7-M put first in IDE mode and then in AHCI mode, but still to no avail:
setpci changes the offset values as I would like, but not even **grub4dos** can identify the SSD:
after a few minutes from loading, it ends in the `grub>` console, and then `ls (hd0,0)` just hangs (while **grub4dos** floppy alone with controller stuck in IDE just boots Windows as expected).
Here is a [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IUpvNiNJ_L9YeV6t-Naa6ijab4VPVecm/view?usp=sharing) of the diff IDE - AHCI, and the [autoexec commands](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lXxBP2xiC8iN0UZI3tX04NlAAU8YniUJk6E73VF9RIM/edit?usp=sharing) I issued from DOS.
I move into uncharted territory, and if I have not made mistakes in my attempt, I begin to think that my BIOS mutilations are not workable this way.

Comment: Old post, and one which assumes BIOS firmware to set AHCI mode, but .... https://superuser.com/questions/954317/win7-turning-on-ahci

Comment: Old enough not to use an answer, but in a nutshjel. Try boot in IDE mode, If they works regedit "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / SYSTEM / CurrentControlset / Services / msahci" to start. Shutdown. Put AHCI mode back in grub2. Boot and pray.

Comment: Thank you @Hennes for your reply. I've already applied [Mom's advice](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/error-message-occurs-after-you-change-the-sata-mode-of-the-boot-drive-0e3ab9b8-99aa-c2b3-1f27-dc9eaf58a14b) to Windows, but it stays stuck in IDE mode, because by imparting only the string `setpci -s 0:1f.2 90.b=40` boot fails with **"error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'."** - if I omit the string, the chipset in IDE is and in IDE it remains - that's why I think there is a need for more **setpci** strings, which unfortunately I don't know how to write.

Comment: To be more precise, a correctly sorted and well populated list of **setpci** strings - something like the three scripts mentioned circa middle of page at [post#7](https://web.archive.org/web/20120712131331/http:/forum.notebookreview.com/hardware-components-aftermarket-upgrades/460478-ich7-m.html) (which still don't work for me in the original form) but entering the [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SEHPkaJd_87FzjKVdnGSVtQzrrZKYMHwiuq9S3tgOc8/edit?usp=sharing) of my Sony.