# Should I separate the two boot drives?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, boot, ssd, bios

I'm currently in IDE mode (no RAID) and have the first drive with Ubuntu 14.04.  The 2nd drive with Windows 10.  I'd hoped to go into BIOS and just switch the primary boot drive.  The other two SSD drives is purely for storage and backups.

When I try to boot to windows I find the drive frozen and I must jump through several hoops to unfreeze it.  It's either locked or frozen when I try to boot into windows. If I didn't have a scanner that doesn't work with Ubuntu, I'd ditch windows forever.

Also, the ACHI settings in BIOS is for all the drives or none of the drives.  How do I switch Ubuntu from IDE to ACHI?  If I have to reinstall windows, so be it.  I have drive 1=Ubuntu, drive 2=Windows, drive 3 & 4=Storage.

Should I separate the two boot drives?

Comment: If you only use windows to use your scanner, consider setting up a Virtual Machine inside your ubuntu with Windows on it and use your scanner that way.

Answer (score 0):

> the ACHI settings in BIOS is for all the drives or none of the drives.

The setting is for the controller and affects all the drives connected to that controller. If you only have once SATA controller then it affects all drives. If you have a motherboard with multiple (e.g. 8 drives via the Intel chips, 4 more via an extra SATA controller then it affects the subset connected to the controller which settinfs you changed.

> How do I switch Ubuntu from IDE to ACHI?

Look up, shout `Khazam!`. You should be all done.

(As in: You do not have do to anything for most Linux or BSD installations. Normal SATA (AHCI) drivers should already exist in your kernel.)

For windows it is more complex: Either change the settings and reinstall windows, or change some of windows services. I have done that on windows 7 (as decribed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/432022/ahci-mode-gave-me-two-boot-options) but I have not yet tried this with win10).

For completeness sake, your settings seem to be:

- AHCI. This is the normal mode for SATA
- IDE/legacy: Backward compatability mode. Needed for things like windows 2000 or older. (or windows XP unless you load the relevant AHCI driver during installation).
- RAID; This is software RAID and will need drivers. Both in windows and in Linux (drivers might already be present in Linux but you may have to adjust /etc/fstab to mount the new devices).

> I have drive 1=Ubuntu, drive 2=Windows, drive 3 & 4=Storage.

There is no need to put windows and Ubuntu on their own drives. Putting them on different partitions in the same drive would works just as well. It does not harm though.

> When I try to boot to windows I find the drive frozen and I must jump through
>   several hoops to unfreeze it.

Did you enable encryption or a password for this drive? Because with the current information in your post we cannot help you.

> If I didn't have a scanner that doesn't work with Ubuntu,
>   I'd ditch windows forever.

If you only need windows for a scanner then I would look into WINE or a VM.